# webpack require (jquery) won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I just started to use webpack and am trying to load jquery synchronously

Here is my main.js

```
var $ = require('jquery');

require('javascript/index.js');
require('less/index.less');
```

and here is my webpack.config

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './assets/javascript/main.js',
    output: {
        path: './assets',
        filename: '/javascript/bundle.js'
    },
    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test: /\.css/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!less-loader")
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("/css/[name].css")
    ],
    resolve : {
        root: path.resolve('./assets'),
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.less']
    }
};
```

my index.js looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var body = $('body');

    var backgrounds = new Array(
        'url(./../images/bg1.jpg)' ,
        'url(./../images/bg2.jpg)' ,
        'url(./../images/bg3.jpg)' ,
        'url(./../images/bg4.jpg)'
    );
    var current = 0;

    function nextBackground() {
        console.log("Changing bg");
        current++;
        current = current % backgrounds.length;
        body.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
    }

    setInterval(nextBackground, 1000);

    body.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
});
```

and on execution throws the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I really don't understand this error since if I look into the generated bundle.js Jquery clearly is getting defined.

I already tried to add this to my resolve:

```
resolve : {
    root: path.resolve('./assets'),
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.less'],
    alias: {
        jquery: "jquery"
    }
}
```

but the error is still persistent

Edit: Here is a snipped of the created bundle.js

```
var $ = __webpack_require__(2);

    __webpack_require__(3);
    __webpack_require__(4);
```

Comment: does only requireing jquery not work?

Comment: If I look into the `bundle.js` it seems to require everything correctly. (also jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, you need to add this to your **index.js**

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

That's because when you used the webpack to build your code, each files(e.g index.js) would be wrap into a function which is defined by webpack.

**So all the variables defined in your main.js are not accessable to index.js**, coz they are now in different function which are not sharing the same scope.

You can either expose jquery to global(`window`) use the [**expose-loader**](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader) or you need to require the **jquery** manually.

Hope this can solve your problem. : )

Comment: ahh I understand, in my case the $ was only getting defined locally in a function. Thanks for clearing this up, it's working now. I also will look into expose-loader

Comment: @JakobAbfalter Exactly. Enjoy : )

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin):

> Automatically loaded modules. Module (value) is loaded when the identifier (key) is used as free variable in a module. The identifier is filled with the exports of the loaded module.

For example: 
Add this plugin to your config:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery"
})
```

Somewhere in your code:

```
// in a module
$("#item") // <= just works
// $ is automatically set to the exports of module "jquery"
```

Make sure you got jquery installed via NPM